# change the backgoroun images dynamically in blackberry eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

Please help me how to change the selected background image dynamically please give me sample example...

I Need to change My application background image when i select the particular image from drop-down list, If click on apply button that image will be display in the background.

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try hooking up your button to a listener, then using [Background](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/) to create your background before using setBackground() to change the background.

If this doesn't update the way you want, overwrite the layout() method in your screen and call the setBackground() in there, then call UIApplication.getUIApplication().relayout() to get it to layout the screen again (be sure to do it in a synchronize block!)

Good luck!